# Utilizando cache durante a sessão do usuário

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc, cache

Estou usando OutputCache em uma aplicação asp.net mvc5  para cachear uma lista na minha aplicação esta da seguinte forma :

```
[(Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "none")]
public ActionResult Index()
{}
```

só que preciso aproveitar esse cache enquanto o usuário estiver logado na aplicação. ou seja eu só vou carregar a lista novamente no novo login do usuário.

como posso definir isso?

Answer (score 0):

Para isso você pode escrever a sua própria regra para o cache usando `VaryByCustom`.

Nesse caso, você precisa escrever o método `GetVaryByCustomString` quer irá retornar se deve ou não usar o cache baseado na `Session`. Supondo que você tenha por exemplo uma sessão com o login do usuário chamada "Login", poderia fazer assim:

```
[(Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "none" aryByCustom="SessionLogin")]
public ActionResult Index() {  }
```

E escrever esse método na **global.asax**:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg) 
{ 
  if(arg == "SessionLogin") 
  { 
    var login = context.Request.Session["Login"]; 
    if (login != null) 
      return login.ToString(); 
  } 
  return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg); 
}
```

Comment: Mas no caso ainda teria a duração de 60ms na declaração, e esse tempo não tem que ser parâmetro enquanto o usuário esta logado aproveita ele saca ? isso que esta confuso pra mim, pois eu sou obrigado a declarar esse tempo.

Comment: O tempo de cache nunca vai bater com o tempo da sessão. Mesmo que a sessão tenha um timeout igual, ela pode ser renovada. Se você usar um parâmetro maior em `Duration`  funcionaria bem, mas ainda assim não expira junto com a sessão. Se quer se seja exatamente igual à sessão, mais fácil colocar o resultado da `Action` na sessão.